# Constructor confusion: setting boolean to int parameter

Tags: java

```
public class Customer{
    private String name;
    private boolean child;
    private boolean student;

    public Customer(String nameIn, int age, boolean studentIn)
        name = nameIn;
        child = age;
        sutdent = studentIn;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public boolean isChild(){
        return age;
        if (age >= 0 && age <= 16){
            child = true;
        }
        else child = false;
        return child;
    }

    public boolean isStudent(){
        if studentIn = true{
             studentIn = true;
        }
        else 
            student = false;
        return student;
    }
}
```

Hello, I've been stuck on an assignment for a paper on Java for quite some hours now. This is one of two classes, the other being an application class. The problem I'm having is with the constructor class - I'm not sure what to assign 'int age' to. As you can see I've tried to assign it to the 'boolean child' but this doesn't make sense to me. Am I missing something here? I understand the rest of the code is a bit of a mess, but once I figure out the constructor class I should be able to smooth out any other kinks myself.

Comment: Why do you have to assign it to anything?

Comment: because "age cannot be resolved to a variable"

Comment: You obviously know what a field is since you're already using them. I don't understand what you're struggling with.

Comment: in "isChild()" it is returning  "return age;"  at the very first line??

Answer (score 0):

In your constructor, age is an int, and you are trying to assign that integer to a boolean field.

What you need to do is calculate whether the Customer is a child and then assign that result to the field. So your class should look like

```
public class Customer{
  private String name;
  private boolean child;
  private boolean student;
  private int age;

public Customer(String nameIn, int age, boolean studentIn)
    this.name = nameIn;
    this.age = age;
    this.student = studentIn;
    this.child = isChild();
}

public String getName(){
    return name;
}

public boolean isChild(){
    if (age >= 0 && age <= 16){
        return true;
    }
    else child = false;
    return child;
}

public boolean isStudent(){
    if studentIn = true{
         studentIn = true;
    }
    else 
        student = false;
    return student;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a member `private boolean child`. This is computed by the age, but you have to remember the age by making a member variable `private int age` then you can assign the age as you like.

```
public class Customer{
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private boolean student;

    public Customer(String nameIn, int ageIn, boolean studentIn)
        name = nameIn;
        age = ageIn;
        sutdent = studentIn;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public boolean isChild(){
        return (age >= 0 && age <= 16);
    }

    public boolean isStudent(){
        return student;
    }
}
```

In the `isStudent()` method you simply need to return the boolean member `student`.

Answer (score 0):

Given that age shouldn't be negative I would suggest validating that in your constructor. Your instance variables should only represent the state of the instance; things such as whether the customer is a child can be derived.

I've made some stylistic suggestions in the suggested code below:

```
public class Customer {
    private final static int MAX_CHILD_AGE = 16;

    private final String name;
    private final int age;
    private boolean student;

    public Customer(String name, int age) {
        if (age < 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Age is negative");
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.student = false;
    }

    public boolean isChild() {
        return age <= MAX_CHILD_AGE;
    }

    public void setStudent(boolean student) {
        this.student = student;
    }

    public boolean isStudent() {
        return student;
    }
}
```

I've declared the name and age fields as final. I would expect you'll eventually need methods to change them at which point you will need to remove the `final` keyword.

I've also taken the `student` argument out of the constructor. This is just a suggestion: including it is certainly valid. My personal philosophy is that the constructor should only include arguments for `final` fields. If it has a setter method then use that after the constructor. If the class requires complex constructors then use a 'builder' rather than lots of constructor arguments.